# Два сервера VPS. К Главному подключены микротики по Wireguard, а второй сервер подключен к главному в режиме точка точка. Как перенаправить трафик

Tags: instagram, wireguard

Два микротика подключены в WireGuard серверу (10.1.1.1 Называется Альфа, он главный), маршрутизация настроена как надо, все работает. Так же подключено два телефона, с ними тоже все хорошо, маршрутизация полная в сети. Но вот к Альфе подключен еще один сервер, который находиться в Алматы в режиме point to point (типо сказать сервер-сервер 10.1.1.100). на примере инстаграма хотел попробовать сделать следующее. Если сервер Альфа видит что кто то щимиться в инстаграм, что бы он трафик пускал через казахстан.

Я отыскал публичную подсеть инстаграма 157.240.214.0/24 и попробовал прописать маршрут: ip route add 157.240.214.0/24 via 10.1.1.100 dev wg0... Не помогло, по трассировке видно что маршрут не отрабатыват.
Сервера на Debian 11. Буду рад помощи. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы можете самостоятельно [edit] ваш вопрос, для этого не надо использовать ответ.